# SourcesSafe 6.0: Search File Comments

Tags: comments, sourcesafe-6.0

Is it possible to search within a project the comments users added after they checked-in files? (manually can be done by selecting a file, Right Click --> Show History --> select Version --> Details, viewed at Comment pane).

Is it possible to get all files that have as comment lets say '4.4.2' automatically?

Thanks in advance,
Sun

Answer (score 3):

you could create a [SourceSafe History Report](http://www.google.com/search?q=sourcesafe+History+report), via GUI or [command](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2009/08/sometimes-it-is-really-useful-to-be.html) [line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7174xsc2%28VS.80%29.aspx), and search it.